# Do not place the editor on top of the author when zooming in

Tags: bug, design, edits, responsive-design

At a certain zoom level or sufficiently small browser window, respectively, author and editor information do not fit side-by-side anymore and get placed on top of each other. So far so good. However if this happens, the editor goes on top, thus taking the position where you would normally expect the author:

[image: example]

This is exacerbated if you scroll such that the author information is hidden.

Please place the editor information below the author information in this case. This would also take care of the irritating gap if the editor is the author:

[image: example]

Comment: AFAIK, StackExchange does not support zooming in any way shape or form (or maybe this policy has changed since they began making the sites responsive?). I wouldn't be surprised if this gets a [tag:status-declined]

Comment: @angussidney We don't, but this isn't caused by zooming. It's caused by a shrinking display width, which is exactly what responsive design is meant to address. You can replicate it by simply resizing your browser window.

Comment: @animuson: With respect to design, is there any relevant difference between zooming and shrinking the browser window?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft We don't technically support zooming because it actively changes the size of everything on the page, which can cause a lot of really weird and unpredictable oddities (e.g. zooming out when a line was only 1px line causes unexpected behavior in rendering a half pixel). Shrinking the page keeps everything the same size and just rearranges it.

Comment: One common example of a narrower display where this would be a problem is phones.  Having the editor be above the author is very confusing.

Comment: I have a strong feeling that this is a dupe.

Comment: @iBug I found only few reports about iOS app where the order of asker/editor is reversed, but that's not dupe since this question isn't about the app.